# How do I translate CONSTRAINT from PostgreSQL to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, converters

This script is in PostgreSQL. I'd like to convert it to MySQL, how do I get it done?

```
CREATE TABLE language_history (
    pk int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    active boolean,
    jsondata varchar(255),
    polymorphic_type varchar(20),
    id varchar(255),
    name varchar(255),
    description varchar(255),
    markup_description varchar(255),
    latitude double precision,
    longitude double precision,
    version int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT language_history_latitude_check CHECK (((((-90))::double precision <= latitude) AND (latitude <= (90)::double precision))),         
    CONSTRAINT language_history_longitude_check CHECK (((((-180))::double precision <= longitude) AND (longitude <= (180)::double precision)))
);
```

Comment: Try to be more specific. What **Exactly** is the problem? Which of the fields/definitions you don't know how to convert?

Comment: The CONSTRAINT is the main focus, others seems a bit familiar. Thanks.

Comment: So ask how to translate a constraint from postgresql to mysql

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE language_history (
    pk int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    active bool,
    jsondata varchar(255),
    polymorphic_type varchar(20),
    id varchar(255),
    name varchar(255),
    description varchar(255),
    markup_description varchar(255),
    latitude double precision,
    longitude double precision,
    version int NOT NULL
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CONSTRAINT language_history_latitude_check CHECK (((((-90))::double precision <= latitude) AND (latitude <= (90)::double precision))),         
CONSTRAINT language_history_longitude_check CHECK (((((-180))::double precision <= longitude) AND (longitude <= (180)::double precision)))
```

To begin with, this isn't a very good table design for postgres. These contraints that you are having trouble with, is the poor man's implementation of postgis's excellent [Geography type](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography).

What the above constraint does is ensures that the values entired into your lat,lng columns are within the valid ranges for geography Latitudes and Longitudes. (the geography type does that for you by default and gives you a lot of other features).

The simplest thing to do in mysql is to create your table without the constraints. Secondly you could use the mysql [geometry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-datatypes.html) type but it does not give you the data validation automatically.

The third option, which would reproduce the constraint in the postgresql table would be to use a BEFORE INSERT trigger. In that case, add the table without the constraint, and then write the trigger to validate the data before inserting.